# what does ?\xfe mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I came across the following code and couldn't figure out what was going on.

```
def self.eof_packet?(data)
  data[0] == ?\xfe && data.length == 5
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`?` starts a [character literal](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/doc_bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#numeric).

`\x` starts a [hexadecimal escape](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/ruby/doc_bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#string).

Answer (score 2):

Hexadecimal number FE, which is 254

Comment: Not accurate. While in Ruby 1.8 `?\xfe == 254`, this is not the case in Ruby 1.9, since `?\xfe` is actually `String`, not a number.

Comment: @Marc, useful comment.  However, it doesn't warrant a down-vote (don't know if that was you).  Ruby's penchant for breaking compatibility in minor revisions has tripped up many an experienced programmer.  @Nikita's answer is completely correct for 1.8, where `?\xfe` is a Fixnum.

Comment: Thanks very much, all of you.

Comment: @Matthew: The given code compares `data[0]` (a character) with `?\xfe` (a character). That code is fine and it will work in both Ruby 1.8 and 1.9. I feel SO is a great site to educate and learn. I don't think it's a good idea that anyone confuses `?\xfe` with a number and nobody should write `data[0] == 0xFE`

I don't mean to be rude; my understanding is that a downvote is appropriate for an incorrect answer. I'll gladly revert it if this answer gets corrected.

BTW, Ruby 1.9 is anything but a minor revision...

Comment: @Marc, in 1.8, `data[0]`, `254`, `?\xfe`, and `0xFE` are all Fixnums and thus `data[0] == ?\xfe`, `data[0] == 0xFE`, and `data[0] == 254` are all correctly comparing objects of the same type.  This is true regardless of whether `data` is a `String` or `Array`.  Wikipedia and other sources define the minor revision as the part after the period.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hexadecimal character literal.  You can also use `0xfe`, which also works for larger numbers (e.g. `0x100`) that don't fit in a byte.